# How to compare and deploy only one ADF pipeline from one ADF instance to other using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-git-deployment

I have already set up 2 different ADF instances i.e dev and qa. Now I do an active development in dev and have multiple pipelines (PA, PB, PC, PD.. etc), where has qa is stable and has only limited working pipelines. This initial deployment was manual using ARM templates and cli

Now I want to push only PA from dev to qa using Azure devOps. I did set up the code repository from dev and qa in devOps, by following this - [cicd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#automate-continuous-integration-by-using-azure-pipelines-releases)

But this will take all the pipelines from dev and push to qa. I want to see if there is a process to compare/sync the changes between dev and qa (Similar to how we do [schema compare for db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-ver15))

I'm currently facing issues as the IR we use in dev and qa is different and I dont require all the pipelines to be pushed to qa as other pipelines are already present, but only one pipeline check the changes and push. Please suggest me if this can be achieved

Comment: When you use the CD Pipeline to push PA from dev to qa, are you using the ARM template to do this opeartion? In Azure Devops Release Pipeline, are you using the ARM template deployment task ?

Comment: Yes using ARM Template Deployment with an incremental approach, the ARM templates are generated from ADF via publih to adf-publish branch.